# Json.NET don't serialize specific property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have next JSON:

```
"mode":"modeValue",
"format":"formatValue",
"options":{
    "page":1,
    "size":"70",
    "resize":"false",
    "templating":null
}
```

But "options" value object can be different from current, I can have many different options. For example, it can be

```
"options": {
    "page": 2,
    "first": "true",
    "parent": null
}
```

I created a class

```
public class Settings
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mode")]
    public string Mode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "format")]
    public string OutputFormat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "options")]
    public string Options { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to deserialize "options" value, but to set it as string (serialized) in `Options` property.

Note: I'll use this class only for deserialization.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `OnDeserialized` attribute. Here's an example:

```
public class Settings
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mode")]
        public string Mode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "format")]
        public string OutputFormat { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnoreAttribute]
        public string Options { get; private set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "options")]
        private object Temp { get; set; }

        [OnDeserialized]
        private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctx)
        {
            Options = Temp?.ToString();
        }
    }
```

"options" are deserialized into "Temp" property and then "Options" are populated by `Temp.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you! This is work for me, so I'll mark this as "solution".
Can you tell me for what is the `?` after `Temp` in `Options = Temp?.ToString();` ?

Comment: Temp?.ToString() is the short for writing  temp != null ? temp.ToString() : null;

Comment: @Pepo - Viezevingertjes is right. I've added this just to be on the safe side (in case "options" is null or undefined in json)